# Disable background links when popup is displayed

Tags: jquery, html, popup

Website has a popup that you can close by clicking outside the popup. The issue is when the popup is open and the user want to close it by clicking outside the popup : if a link happens to be in the background of the popup, the user will be redirected to an un-wanted destination. [(image for clarity)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D5CU.png)

jquery close pop-up on document

```
$(".popSlide-bg").on("click touchstart", function (e) 
{
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});  

$(document).on("click touchstart", function () 
{   
    if($(".popSlide-bg").is(':visible'))
    {
        $('.popSlide-black-bg').hide();
        $('.popSlide-bg').hide();
    }
});
```

is there any way to add a line which disable website links when popup is visible.

Thank you

Comment: Add `inline-block` or `block` css to popup class

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try add layer to prevent click on background links.
check my jsfiddle below

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#overlay, #popup').css('display', 'block');
});

$('#overlay').click(function(){
    $('#overlay, #popup').css('display', 'none');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Not2Day2Die/u0cppt2z/7/
hope this help

Answer (score 0):

using `e.preventDefault()` saved my issue

```
$(".popSlide-black-bg").on("click touchstart", function (e) 
{   

e.preventDefault();

    if($(".popSlide-bg").is(':visible'))
    {
        $('.popSlide-bg, .popSlide-black-bg').hide();
    } 

});
```